# Scala gives no compile-time error when assigning a value to a number literal?

Tags: scala, runtime-error

While learning `scala` I stumbled upon the following strange snippet:

```
package temptests

object TempTest {
  //def 2 = 123 // does not compile
  val 2 = 123 // compiles, but leads to an exception at runtime

  def main(args: Array[String]) = { // just do something to load this class
    println("Hello")
  }
}
```

I would expect that the compiler would throw an error on `val 2 = 123` because identifiers must not start with a digit, but the code compiles without a warning.
However, at runtime it immediately throws an Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   temptests.TempTest.main(TempTest.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: scala.MatchError: 123 (of class java.lang.Integer)     at
>   temptests.TempTest$.(TempTest.scala:5)  at
>   temptests.TempTest$.(TempTest.scala)  ... 6 more

I am just curious: how is `val 2 = 123` understood by `Scala`? Why is there no compile-time error?

Comment: I'm 100% sure this is a duplicate, but I can't for the life of me find one!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I am just curious: how is `val 2 = 123` understood by Scala?

You can think of `val 2 = 123` as:

```
123 match {
    case 2 => 2
}
```

The variable name part in Scala isn't always a simple name, it can also be a **pattern**, for example:

```
val (x, y) = (1, 2)
```

Will decompose 1 and 2 to x and y, respectively. In scala, everything which is allowed after a *case* statement is also allowed after *val* and is translated to a pattern match.

[From the specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions) (emphasis mine):

> Value definitions can alternatively have **a pattern** as left-hand side.
>   If **p is some pattern** other than a simple name or a name followed by a
>   colon and a type, then the value definition `val p = e` is expanded as
>   follows:

(Skipping to the relevant example):

> If p has a unique bound variable x:

```
val x = e match { case p => x }
```

This is the reason the compiler doesn't emit a compile time error. There is a lengthy discussion of the subject in this [google group question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/k57U6jt8Za0).

Comment: I think the match has to be the other way around as `2` is the pattern that is matched.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! This also shows why `val 2 = 2` works without problems. However, is there *any* example in which it is helpful to have at the left hand side a literal rather than a more general pattern?

Comment: @cubiclettuce Can't think of a reason you'd actually *want* to do that.

Comment: Me neither, but if there is really no use-case, then it would be better if the compiler would catch the special case of a literal at the left hand side, since it cannot be anything meaningful and is likely a typo. But this is really just a minor issue, and I was only interested in understanding "why" anyway.

Comment: @cubiclettuce: It can be harmful for a compiler to have too many special cases like that, since it can make it harder for programmers to learn the underlying rules. (That said, a compiler *warning* would be fully justified.)

Answer (score 3):

The left hand side of a `val` declaration can be a pattern. See [scala language documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions).

so

```
val 2 = 123
```

can be written as

```
123 match {
  case 2 => 2
}
```

which gives a match error.

In real life this is mostly used to extract tuples to readably local vals:

```
val test = ("Foo", 30)
val (name, age) = test
```